# Low Frequency, High Voltage Oscillator

Tags: driver, oscillator, high-voltage

I am trying to create a speed control for a brushless AC motor, like those used in fountain water pumps.  Since the speed of the motor is determined by the line frequency I want to make a low frequency (20 to 60 Hz) high voltage (120 V) oscillator.  Any ideas?  The pump is 7.5 W at 120 V.

Comment: This is too broad a question in its current form.  What have you tried?  What *specifically* are you asking about.  3 phase motor drivers already exist.

Comment: This is a simple permanent magnet rotor surrounded with a field coil driven directly from the AC line.  The rotor turns at a multiple of the line frequency.  By varying the frequency driving the field coil the rotational rate will change proportionally.  A simple high voltage (120 V) multivibrator might work, but as the frequency decreases the impedance of the coil also decreases, increasing the current, etc.  I don't think the shape of the field voltage matters much, but the voltage should decrease with the frequency to keep the field power somewhat constant.

Comment: Continued from above: A low freq oscillator can be implemented many ways, as can a 120 V driver. I am looking for a circuit to do both and hopefully then adjust the voltage to maintain the power to the field.  You are right, I think this should already exist somewhere, but have not been able to find anything.

Comment: It's actually very unlikely that a motor for this application, in this power range, would be a permanent magnet synchronous motor. It's much more likely to be a simple [shaded-pole induction motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor), in which case, you can vary its speed by using a small variac to reduce the available torque.

Comment: Yeah, I took it apart and it is a mag drive with only one coil.  Here is a web link for typical pumps like this.  http://www.drsfostersmith.com/product/prod_display.cfm?c=3578+4587+20396&pcatid=20396

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a variable frequency drive. You would be much better off to just purchase something off the shelf, than to put in the time and materials trying to make one. They aren't that expensive. Here are [some examples](http://www.wolfautomation.com/ProductList.aspx?CategoryID=5103). Read through the specs until you find the one that meets the pump's specs.

Comment: I am sure you are correct, even for small, low power motors is it probably better to buy.  But, I will not learn as much that way....

Answer (score 0):

For a motor under 10 watts, probably the simplest way using off-the-shelf parts is an audio amplifier module (maybe 15-25 watts), driving a mains transformer in reverse.

It won't be quite as efficient as you would like at low speeds because the transformer is designed for 50 or 60 Hz. The dominant problem will be the inductance of the secondary (which you are using as a primary) which appears to the amplifier as an impedance in parallel with the load (the motor). As you reduce the frequency, this impedance reduces, increasing wasted power.

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Good ideas.  I would like to eliminate the transformer and just switch the rectified mains at the new freq.  Maybe use the pump coil as part of the osc?  To minimalist?

Comment: You certainly can switch or amplify straight from the rectified mains, but it means a lot more design work and care on your part, instead of using well proven and safe (LV) circuits for most of the work.